# How to override the debug variable format in Intellij Idea's debug window when inheriting a container (Vector)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a class `ValueList<K, V>` that extends `Vector<V>` and adds bunch of other attributes to it.
The declaration of the class is:

```
public class ValueList<K extends Comparable<K>, V> extends Vector<V> implements Comparable<ValueList<K, V>>
```

When debugging, Intellij's debug window has the format of `ValueList` the same as `Vector`, not showing the attributes that I added. For example: I have an array of `ValueList`s called `valueLists`, that's how its contents look like:

[image]

Also, I have already overridden `toString()` to print the elements of the `Vector`. What I know is that when I override `toString()`, Intellij prints the object using it on the side, and this is not happening.

**Edit:** the implementation of `toString()`:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("(");
    for (V v : this) {
        builder.append(v).append(", ");
    }
    return builder.append(")").toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click on  your `valueLists` in the debug variables and there should be an option "view as" (name can slightly change depending on your version of IntelliJ) that let you choose how to display these type of values.

You also have a look to this piece of doc: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/customizing-views.html#renderers

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful. I'd like to add that Intellij turns out to be about fully customizable in this matter, you can `create`  from "view as" and customize the view in the debugging window.